# Android button disable multiple clicks

Tags: android, button

I have Search activity with edittext and button, i want disable multiple click on button, How can i?

```
    final Button searchViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_search);

    searchViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startFirstTime();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please up the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isclicked=false;

 final Button searchViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_search);

    searchViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if(!isclicked){
            isclicked=true;
            startFirstTime();
            }
        }
    });

  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (null != arrayOfList && arrayOfList.size() != 0) {

        TOTAL_ITMES = Integer.parseInt(arrayOfList.get(0).getId());

        for (Item item : arrayOfList) {
            mainArrayList.add(item);
        }


    }
    setAdapterToListview();
     isclicked=false;
}
```

Comment: The final local variable isclicked cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Comment: After click startFirstTime() finished. again search button not work. it not re enable

Comment: This one also not work. Still multiple click work and loading multiple result

Answer (score 2):

you could `searchViewButton.setEnabled(false)` when `onClick` is called the first time. This way the button will not be clicked until you call `searchViewButton.setEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
searchViewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        searchViewButton.setEnabled(false);
        startFirstTime();
    }
});

public void startFirstTime() {
   ....do stuff.....
   searchViewButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: If i add it in searchViewButton.setEnabled(true); in startFirstTime(), i have error searchViewButton cannot be resolved